# Why does this stored procedure return multiple rows when the query itself does not?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL 8 server.  I can run this query to get a single row of data:

```
        SELECT *, CountOfSeconds/total AS GlobalTimer,
            IF(CorrectAnswer = 'A', CountOfA/total,
                    IF(CorrectAnswer = 'B', CountOfB/total,
                        IF(CorrectAnswer = 'C', CountOfC/total,
                            IF(CorrectAnswer = 'D', CountOfD/total,
                                IF(CorrectAnswer = 'E', CountOfE/total, NULL )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ) AS GlobalAccuracy
            FROM(
                SELECT *, (CountOfA+CountOfB+CountOfC+CountOfD+CountOfE) AS total
                FROM mydb.questions WHERE QID=6522
            )AS tbl
```

But when I turn it into a stored procedure like the one below:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `QuestionDetails`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `QuestionDetails`(
    IN qid INT(11)
    )
BEGIN
        SELECT *, CountOfSeconds/total AS GlobalTimer,
            IF(CorrectAnswer = 'A', CountOfA/total,
                    IF(CorrectAnswer = 'B', CountOfB/total,
                        IF(CorrectAnswer = 'C', CountOfC/total,
                            IF(CorrectAnswer = 'D', CountOfD/total,
                                IF(CorrectAnswer = 'E', CountOfE/total, NULL )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ) AS GlobalAccuracy
            FROM(
                SELECT *, (CountOfA+CountOfB+CountOfC+CountOfD+CountOfE) AS total
                FROM questions WHERE QID=qid
            )AS tbl;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then I get as many rows as there exist in the `questions` table. How could this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WHERE QID=qid

The argument to your procedure has the same name as the column name. This is basically interpreted as `1 = 1`

You would need to give a different name to the procedure argument, like `p_qid` for example, so MySQL can distinguish it from the column name.

Also, these nested `IF` statement are hard to read an understand. I would suggesting rewriting this with `CASE`:

New code:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `QuestionDetails`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `QuestionDetails`(IN p_qid INT(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tbl.*, 
        CountOfSeconds/total AS GlobalTimer,
        CASE CorrectAnswer
            WHEN 'A' THEN CountOfA/total
            WHEN 'B' THEN CountOfB/total
            WHEN 'C' THEN CountOfC/total
            WHEN 'D' THEN CountOfD/total
            WHEN 'E' THEN CountOfE/total
        END AS GlobalAccuracy
        FROM(
            SELECT 
                q.*, 
                CountOfA + CountOfB + CountOfC + CountOfD + CountOfE AS total 
            FROM questions q 
            WHERE QID = p_qid
        )AS tbl;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: **palm-on-forehead

Comment: the problem is also eliminated if all column references are qualified by the table name or table alias, e.g. `q.qid = p_qid`  (this is just one more example that demonstrates that best practice is to qualify *all* column references)

Comment: I'm a novice but I wonder: your rewrite doesn't seem to have a default case.  Would it return a different result from the original if CorrectAnswer doesn't match any case?

Comment: @BeetleJuice: `CASE` returns `NULL` when none of the conditions are satifisfied. That's consistent with what your imbricated `IF`s do.

Comment: Ok.  for `q.*` in your rewrite to work, wouldn't you need to declare `q` as the alias to the inner table?

Comment: @BeetleJuice: you are right. I fixed that.